# Does LDAP require that the password be revealed on the server side

Tags: security, flask, ldap

I am integrating an application with LDAP in my organisation.

I am implementing HTTPS to send the password from the frontend to my application server, and then forwarding the password from my application server to the LDAP server using TLS. This keeps the password safe in transit.

However there is still the problem that my application server is still able to see the password in plaintext before it forwards the password to the LDAP server.

If I hash it on the front end then the password will not match the password on the LDAP server.

Is this a risk that I need to accept in order to integrate my application with LDAP? Or am I implementing this incorrectly somehow?

My application server is a python flask application and I am implementing LDAP3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the question:

> Is this a risk that I need to accept in order to integrate my
>   application with LDAP?
>   Yes.

The use of SASL Mechanisms which are supported by most LDAP Server Implementations can SASL authentication, this is  However, this requires the LDAP Client (DUA) to be able to present an encoded value that contains the SASL mechanism name and an optional set of encoded SASL credentials.

Maybe you could use SASL with a [ServerLess Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html)?

Regardless of the technology implemented, any password based authentication would require the user providing credentials which, at some point need to be gathered and therefore subject to this risk.

THe use of [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) could limit the exposure so the to the OpenID Provider's Authorization Server; but the risk is still present.

[WebAuthn](https://webauthn.io/) eliminates passwords and may be an option.

-jim